# C# - Loading assembly at runtime, method called on instance seems to be ineffective

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies

I'm trying to load an assembly, instantiate a class from that assembly, and then call Run(), which should set a property inside this instance.

Loading the assembly seems to work fine as I'm able to list the types, but the called method seems to be ineffective: the property located in the new instance remains set to null, depsite the fact that it should be set to something.

I also tried calling the method using a type.InvokeMethod(...) syntax.

Method that loads the assembly, calls the constructor and calls the method:

```
private IEntryPoint ChargerAppli(AppInfo ai)
{
        string cheminAssemblies = "D:\\TFS\\OBL Microsoft\\Stages\\2010\\WPF\\Shell\\Shell\\Applications\\";

        Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(cheminAssemblies + ai.AssemblyName);
        Type type = a.GetType(ai.StartupClass);

        IEntryPoint instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IEntryPoint;
        instance.Run();
        return instance;
}
```

IEntryPoint interface:

```
public interface IEntryPoint
{
    FrameworkElement HostVisual { get; set; }
    void Run();
}
```

IEntryPoint implementation that I'm trying to load, which is located in the new assembly:

```
class Bootstrap : IEntryPoint
{
    private FrameworkElement _visuel;

    public Bootstrap()
    {
        //do some work;
        this._visuel = new MainVisual();
    }

    public System.Windows.FrameworkElement HostVisual { get; set; }

    public void Run()
    {
        HostVisual = this._visuel;
    }
}
```

What may I be missing?

Comment: What you can do to troubleshoot this is: 1) include Debug.Write statements and see what you have in VS.NET 2) write the same code but reference an assembly directly without Reflection and make sure that it works as you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the assembly is working, here is a simplified piece of code that I have used to accomplish the same task.

```
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
 Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
 foreach (Type t in types)
 {
    MethodInfo[] methods = t.GetMethods();

   if (t.Name == "MyType")
   {
       foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
       {
           if (method.Name == "Run")
           {
               try
               {
                   InterfaceToMyType activeModule = ("InterfaceToMyType")method.Invoke(null, args);
               }
               catch
               {
                    //do stuff here if needed
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot.
The assembly is indeed working, and I also need to return the actual instance of the desired type, therefore I called Activator.CreateInstance() after I reach the desired type in the foreach.
Thanks for your input, this has been of great help.

Comment: Glad to have helped - many people on this community have helped me, so I try and be helpful when I can. :)